# [: : bad number on the bash script

Tags: bash, unix, freebsd

This is my bash script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash -x

touch /usr/local/p
touch /usr/local/rec
DATA_FULL=`date +%Y.%m.%d.%H`
CHECK=`netstat -an | grep ESTAB | egrep '(13001|13002|13003|13004|13061|13099|16001|16002|16003|16004|16061|16099|18001|18002|18003|18004|18061|18099|20001|20002|20003|20004|20061|20099|13000|16000|18000|20000)' | awk '{ print $5 }' | sort -u | wc -l`
netstat -an | grep ESTAB | egrep '(13001|13002|13003|13004|13061|13099|16001|16002|16003|16004|16061|16099|18001|18002|18003|18004|18061|18099|20001|20002|20003|20004|20061|20099|13000|16000|18000|20000)' | awk '{ print $5 }' | sort -u | wc -l > /usr/local/www/p

STAT=`cat /usr/local/www/rec`
if [ "$CHECK" -gt "$STAT" ]; then
echo $CHECK"\n"$DATA_FULL > /usr/local/p
fi
```

Ofcourse I've runned `chmod +x script.sh` and then `sh script.sh`, then I receive the following message: `[: : bad number`.

Why does it happends?

Comment: Does `/usr/local/www/rec` contains any number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are integer for sure, use this syntax,

```
if [ "0$(echo $CHECK|tr -d ' ')" -gt "0$(echo $STAT|tr -d ' ')" ];
```

A simple hack. Only works if $STAT is always either empty or positive number.

Comment: Still: `[: 0       1: bad number
`

Comment: Keep in mind that the `$CHECK` is returning 1 + there are some whitespaces before the `1`, look at this image: `http://i.imgur.com/DB5y4.jpg` the gray background is the selected output.

Comment: @Cyclone then you could always trim it. before or inside the condition.

Comment: Thanks :) now everything is fine :)

Answer (score 3):

Run your script using

```
sh -x script.sh
```

It'll print every line it executes and the variable output.
Run the netstat command and stat command outside and check.

Comment: whatever netstat outputs, `wc -l` is not likely to yield non-numeric result, so it basically comes down to inspection of the `/usr/local/www/rec` file.

Answer (score 1):

probably your `/usr/local/www/rec` is empty. Try

```
STAT=`cat /usr/local/www/rec 2>/dev/null || echo 0`
```

maybe.

Comment: You mean `/usr/local/www/rec` ?

Comment: I prepend "0" so its `"0$STAT"`. Check my answer

Comment: Yes, that should also do. I am always afraid of prepending zero because then I have to think if it will turn into octal ;-)

Comment: No it doesn't turn into octal.  I have tested it using, `touch as; em=$(cat as); if [ "090" -gt "0$em" ]; then echo Greater; else echo Smaller; fi;`

Comment: I know, what I meant is that you have to consider whether it will or won't. That was my lame excuse ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that both `STAT` and `CHECK` are numbers that can be compared with `-gt`?

Comment: `STAT` is a empty file while the `CHECK` is returning: `        1
` (with the whitespaces).

Comment: So you can't compare the two as numbers. You probably have to catch that error before comparing the two.